# "StaticJsonBuffer" was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I made a web server on a NodeMCU ESP8266 module for sending some information.
I can send JSON string's but if I try to make a `StaticJsonBuffer` I get an error that is not declared but I have it included. ArduinoJson version 6.5.0-beta.

Here's my a part of my code:

```cpp
void getData(){
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
  root["Temperature"] = Temperature;
  root["Humidity"] = Humidity;
  String json;
  root.prettyPrintTo(json);
  if(server.hasArg("plain") == false){
    server.send(200, "application/json", json);
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dynamic JSON Buffer instead, you don't have to initialize size in it. 6.5.0 is not a stable version. So better use version 5 these are stable version and have all the functions working. Dynamic JSON Buffer is working fine with 6.5.0 beta version.

```cpp
void getData(){
    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
    root["Temperature"] = Temperature;
    root["Humidity"] = Humidity;
    String json;
    root.prettyPrintTo(json);
    if(server.hasArg("plain") == false){
        server.send(200, "application/json", json);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have searched a little bit on the ArduinoJson.org and found out that it is recommended to use ArduinoJson version 5.x. Because versions 6.x is in beta an has some changes and bugs ...